# Safe maximum number of records read by fread

Tags: c, mingw, fread

I am using fread to read a large chunk of image data (> 1 MB) from a file. I recently encountered a bug on MinGW with Windows network shares where a single call to fread like

```
fread(file, 4, 100000, data);
```

fails reliably with an "Invalid argument" error, but 10 calls of

```
fread(file, 4, 10000, data); data += 10000;
```

succeed and yield the right result. I deduce there must be a maximum size for an fread, which I was not aware of before. I bisected the allowed size of fread and found it to be between 31000 and 32000 blocks of 4 bytes. Has anyone encountered this before? Is this a bug in MinGW? Is there any way to determine the maximum "safe" size for fread?

Comment: That's pretty strange, especially since `EINVAL` is not a documented error code for `fread`. How are you doing your error checking?

Comment: Is `file` a `FILE *`? because the first argument to `fread` is the buffer, not the file.

Comment: Hasturkun: Sorry, garbled my arguments. file is a float* and data is a FILE*.

Comment: I am checking the existence of an error with ferror() and getting the error message via strerror() (and perror() gives the same result).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a known bug in MSVCRT (the Microsoft Visual C Runtime, which mingw uses) that `fread` (and perhaps also the underlying `_read` or whatever..?) fails on moderately long read lengths. You can either break the read down into smaller parts, write your own version of `fread` to replace the system one (but only do this when compiling on broken systems!), or switch to a better runtime environment (like cygwin) that's not full of bugs...

Comment: Compiling on broken systems?  Do you mean compiling *for* broken systems?

Answer (score 2):

`fread()` is not supposed to return a short item count unless a read error or end-of-file is reached.  This sounds like a bug in the C library you're linking against (doesn't MinGW link against Microsoft's C library by default?).